# ListView with images from URL source

Tags: c#, facebook, image, listview, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to do a ListView with images, but the source of the images is from a URL not from a directory on local pc using FB's API.

**Exemple:**

Person X   [Profile pic of person]

Person Y   [Profile pic of person]

Person Z   [Profile pic of person]

**I tried**

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
pb.ImageLocation = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture";
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)pb.Image;
IntPtr Hicon = bmp.GetHicon();
Icon myIcon = Icon.FromHandle(Hicon);
imageList1.Images.Add(FriendList.data[i].name, myIcon );
lv.Items.Add(FriendList.data[i].name, i);
```

I can get the image and set it in a picture box normally, but when I try the code above i keep getting **NullReferenceException** on **IntPtr Hicon = bmp.GetHicon()**

Am I doing something wrong? If yes, is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: My money is on `bmp` is `null`

Comment: Yea after debugging it turned out the bmp is always null.. Why?

Comment: did you try this method? [PictureBox.Load(string URL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ak7was.aspx) that will make your code more simple in first step.  then i would debug if the image really exists.

Comment: The image exists.. I'll try ur method right now thanks @Koryu

Comment: Lol thanks a lot it worked.. Can you write ur method as answer so I can accept it :) ? thanks @Koryu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try this method? [PictureBox.Load(string URL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ak7was.aspx)